# How can I fix 'moving text(label) continuously with some space in C#'?

Tags: c#, marquee

I have some c# code for moving text such as marquee tag in HTML.
I'd like to move 2nd text after 1st text when not disappear.

```
string[] ss;
int index = 0;        

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (clsBas.SCREEN_TEXT != "") //multiline text
    {
        lblScreenText.Text = ss[index];

        if (lblScreenText.Left < 0 && (Math.Abs(lblScreenText.Left) > lblScreenText.Width))
        {
            lblScreenText.Left = 1920;//panel width 
            index++;    
        }

        lblScreenText.Left = lblScreenText.Left - 15;

        if (index == ss.Length)
        {
            index = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question/ problem? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55451007/edit) your question to include it

Comment: To make our day easier. Maybe you need to show an example of input and how output is expected.

Comment: I'd like to make "MOVING TEXT" such as marquee tag in HTML using multi text lines. For example, There are 2 text lines. AAAAA, BBBBB. At first, AAAAA move right to left. BBBBB start before when AAAAA is still moving.
This code is working well. But BBBBB start after AAAAA is gone.